# Android Studio Number Picker

Tags: android-studio, numberpicker

I want to use a `NumberPicker` in Android Studio but instead of numbers I want to set a string array. I found a similar question but the problem is: I have more than 10000 strings and Android Studio doesn't work with more than ?(I don't know) items. What can I do?

Comment: Probably you are looking for the [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) control?

Comment: in Visual studio with c# I used StreamReader of a file. but I don't know reading methods of Java so I created an array of string

Comment: If you want to go with the spinner, you can create a custom adapter which wraps your string array. Or do you want to create a NumberPicker-like control, which allows the user, to change the selected string with the up-down button? Because to do that you have to dive into the source of the number picker, and figure out how that works.

Comment: Yes, maybe the spinner is better

Answer (score 0):

Copy-pasting from the Spinner sample, this is pretty straight forward, if you have the array:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerId);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(
     yourContextRef // If this is in an activity, then simply this
     , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item // the layout of an item
     , yourStringArray // Your string array
);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```